# how to pass value from handler to method

Tags: java, android, handler

I have a problem on passing a value obtained from handler to another method in the same class, as shown below, edit: on the Class.myvalue come with cannot be resolved or not a field, am i correct on the use of set and get?

```
public static double getMyValue() { return myValue; //OR return Class.myValue 
}

public static double setMyValue(double myValue) { Class.myValue = myValue;}
private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        String data;
        switch (msg.what) {
        case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
            switch (msg.arg1) {
            case BluetoothRfcommClient.STATE_CONNECTED:
                mBTStatus.setText(R.string.title_connected_to);
                mBTStatus.append("\n" + mConnectedDeviceName);
                break;
            case BluetoothRfcommClient.STATE_CONNECTING:
                mBTStatus.setText(R.string.title_connecting);
                break;
            case BluetoothRfcommClient.STATE_NONE:
                mBTStatus.setText(R.string.title_not_connected);
                break;
            }
            break;
        case MESSAGE_READ: // todo: implement receive data buffering

            byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;


            String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

            Toast.makeText(GaitViewGraph.this, readMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //double value = Double.parseDouble(readMessage); // convert byte array to double
            //changedvalue = value;
            double value = Double.parseDouble(readMessage);
            setMyValue(value);
```

---

after i convert byte array to double, i would like to pass this "value" to this method (getChangevalue)

```
 private double getChangevalue() {
       return getMyValue();
}
```

So how can i do it? or is there any way to get the value out of handler? Please advice..

Answer (score 2):

you use `handler.sendMessage()` to pass some value.

```
Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

                bundle.putString("myKey", "abc");
                 msg.setData(bundle);
                 handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

you cna read more [here](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/A_Basic_Overview_of_Android_Threads_and_Thread_handlers)

Comment: i am in the 'public void handleMessage(Message msg) {' to get data from bluetooth device, then i would like to pass this data to a method in the same class named 'private double getChangevalue() {'

Answer (score 1):

I think, that using an setter for a static variable would work in this.
Edit:
Just add this

`private static double myValue = 0.0D;`

```
public static void getMyValue() { return myValue; /*OR return Class.myValue*/ }
public static double setMyValue(double myValue) { Class.myValue = myValue;}
```

and this is add above the handler.

To use it then, call setMyValue() to get just call getMyValue();

Comment: i am not quite sure what it is, can u provide an example for me?

Comment: Yeah, look here. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbp.html or just use a reference to some static variable.

Comment: sorry, still not sure where to implement them. what to put under my handler and where to call it? `private String name;
    private String salutation;

    public void createSalutation() {
        this.salutation = greeting.greet(name);
    }

    public String getSalutation() {
        return salutation;
    }`

Comment: I think that you should go and learn the programming basics, like how to use these accessors, what would help you a lot.

Comment: i noticed that, but as a student, my project due is coming, so i will have to rush on it and learn more basic later.